# Kylo | Access Template Exception

Tags: kylo

I created a a role in Kylo and assigned only create/update feed permission.

[image]

I was able to create a feed but when i tried to access it I got an access template exception.

[image]

Any pointers here?

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling the Access Templates permission. Kylo needs access to the template in order to create a feed.

Comment: Provided access template permission. it works...Users will be able to see list of template installed but wont be able to edit anything..